# Editar pergunta de baixa qualidade, mal formatada e negativada

Tags: debate, edição

Já me deparei com pergunta do tipo "faça para mim", que já está negativada, porém ainda não fechada, e que  está cheia de problemas de formatação como:

- falta de capitalização
- falta de acentuação
- erros de grafia
- falta de quebra de linhas

Esses problemas tornam a pergunta ainda pior de se ler.

Nesse caso editar a pergunta estaria promovendo uma pergunta ruim para o topo? Melhor não mexer, e deixar ela se perder no tempo? Só sinalizar? Ou sem exceções, deve ser editada?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se estiver pouco negativada dá um *bump* nela sim. Se estiver muito negativada (não lembro se -3, -4 ou -5) não muda nada.

Arrumar essas coisas em pergunta que ainda está bem problemática não sei se vale o esforço. Talvez só o autor consiga arrumar o problema mais importante e talvez ele desarrume tudo. Não estou dizendo que não deve, menos ainda que não pode, mas eu dificilmente (tudo tem exceção) faria alguma edição se não puder salvar a pergunta como um todo. Pode ser que se estiver melhor escrita alguém tente ajudar salvar o resto. Então depende de cada um, não há recomendação oficial, a não ser que ajudar, sempre que possível, é algo bom a se fazer.

Mas não porque ela será "subida". Subi-la pode ser útil para mais pessoas tentarem ajudar ou para fechar logo.